# What does $\; \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \arccos x =i\infty \;$ mean?

Tags: limits, inverse

Is there somone who can show me what $\; \lim_{x\to\infty} (\arccos x) =i\infty \;$ means?

Does it meant that limit does not  exist? $\:$ If yes, how can one prove that limit does not exist?

Note : $\arccos$ is the inverse function of $\cos$

Thank you for any kind of help

Comment: Label a real and complex graph, go up north, it gets cold up there being alone for all eternity with only imaginary friends to comfort you...$i \cdot \infty$

Comment: I seek , is lim arccos x exist when x go to infty ? and how to show that ?

Comment: look cos x at infty doesn't exist , is it the same with it inverse ?

Comment: The cosine function has no inverse both in the real and the complex case; at best $\arccos$ is multivalued, so you should (1) tell what definition of $\arccos$ you're using; (2) what's the supposed meaning of $i\infty$ (I can't think of one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real function $\arccos x$ is defined for $-1 \le  x \le 1$.  Not for $x>1$.  But the complex function $\arccos x$ is defined for all $x$.  If $w = \arccos x$, then $\cos w = x$, so that
$$
\frac{e^{iw}+e^{-iw}}{2} = x
$$
and we may solve a quadratic equation to see
$$
\arccos x = i \log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\;\right)
$$
when $x>1$.  Can you do the limit of this as $x \to \infty$?

**added**

As $x \to +\infty$ along the real axis, $\arccos x$ goes to $i\infty$, which we can see by watching it follow the imaginary axis upward in the complex plane.

Comment: I surely can't.

Comment: Somewhat more precisely, the "standard" branch cuts for arccos are on the real intervals $(-\infty, -1)$ and $(1,\infty)$; for large positive $x$ the imaginary part is positive below the branch cut and negative above the branch cut.

Comment: thank you for your answer , do you meant that limit for complex function doesn't exist ?

Comment: The function diverges to infinity in a particular way (which is what the formula in the question means).  If you like you can say "the limit does not exist" which has less information.

Comment: yes, i meant if the limit written above meant that doesn't exist or diverge ?

Comment: now , I understand that for complex function "divergence" and for real function it doesn't exist .

Comment: Most importantly, for $x > 1$ the function is purely imaginary (i.e. it has a real part equal to zero), so the function diverges to the "infinity" point on the imaginary axis (as opposed to something like $e^x$ which diverges to $+\infty$, or $(1+i)x$ which diverges to the upper-right of the complex plane).